# Sanitizing a meat rack

Tags: food-safety, cleaning, barbecue, utensils, mold

If a meat roaster rack has become contaminated with mold, etc, would soaking it in hot water and bleach (0.5 cup bleach to 1 gal of hot water) for 2 - 1 hour cycles with hard scrubbing between soaks the baking in the oven at 450°F for 1 hour be sufficient to kill any toxins that may be present?

Comment: No proof but that seems excessive. I reckon most BBQ grills get mouldy at some point. If mine does it gets a clean with detergent+bleach, a good rinse, then thoroughly heated as the coals start to burn. That seems like plenty.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go crazy, you just need to get all the grease and accumulated gunk off of it to make it safe to use. Bleach won't help you get it clean, it will only sterilize, and then only if the water itself is clean - there's no point putting chlorine in dirty water. If you want something to help you get it clean a heavy duty kitchen cleaner or something like simple green is what you are looking for, although lots of liquid dish soap and a scourer will probably do just fine. If you get it good and clean you won't need to use chlorine or bake it because you'll have removed anything potentially harmful, but if once you clean it you still want extra assurance then wiping it down with a chlorine solution or baking it as you suggest will work - both is overkill.

Comment: Yes. The only reason my BBQ gets bleach (as in my comment) is that I have a spray bottle of kitchen cleaner that's got it mixed with a good degreasing detergent. If there are particles that you miss, heat will get into them better than bleach

Comment: That works for me too @ChrisH, in fact I rarely use water at all, I usually give my bbq meat rack a brushdown while it's still hot after cooking, which gets rid of a lot. I let it get nice and hot the next use so the heat will get rid of any nasties.

Comment: Yes, I scrape mine after use and leave it over the hot coals, with the lid shut. But a few wet weeks seem to lead to mould anyway.

Comment: Oh definitely, there's always something left.

Answer (score 0):

Just heating it at your 450F for an hour should surely destroy all organisms and their metabolites without any prior washing or bleaching. If you must use an oxidiser, a dilute hydrogen peroxide would be safer than a chlorine based product.